# Windows 10 Edge Opens Momentarily and Then Disappears

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have seen on many threads on other websites that this is a very common issue at the moment with Windows 10. When I try to open Edge it opens for about 1 second, if that, and immediately closes. No error or anything. I read that some people have figured out that it is because Edge makes the home page a summary of the different apps in Windows 10 (Sports, Money, etc.) and Edge trying to load it all causes the crash. I tried a suggestion of opening all of the apps that would be loaded in the home page in advance and then opening Edge, but it made no difference. I was hoping someone else might have some ideas about what to do. It worked for the first week or so after I upgraded and then this issue appeared out of nowhere. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with recent 10 update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a company computer where updating the OS version is not an option.

Following the steps described [here](http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/08/microsoft-edge-closes-immediately.html?showComment=1456485155968#c8539586374193038031) solved the issue:

> 1. Open regedit
> 2. go to location as below
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
>
> 3. right click folder "microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" at the left panel, and click Permission.
> 4. select third Unknown account (S-1-15-3-3624051433 ....)
> 5. You will see only Read permission is selected. Let's check "All permission".
> 6. Click OK and close the window.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue actually resolved itself when Microsoft issued an update for 10. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

I used this method as I had a problem with the start menu not opening running this command in powershell fixed edge shutting down

https://www.techmesto.com/fix-start-menu-broken-windows-10-technical-preview/

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Comment: Welcome at superuser. Please include more information from the cited source than just a pure command.

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.