# Windows 10 UWP apps launch and then disappear immediately

Tags: windows-10, uwp

### **The Problem**

When trying to run certain [Provisioned Windows apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/apps-in-windows-10#provisioned-windows-apps) on Windows 1903, the apps seem to open and then just disappear very quickly—and this is the problem.

### **Troubleshooting**

Upon inspecting the [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) `Application` logs, there are `Event ID 1000` events logged. Furthermore, upon inspection of the **Event Viewer** | `Application and Services Logs` | `Microsoft` | `Windows` | `Apps` and within the `Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` log, there are `Event ID 5961` events logged.

> **Event Viewer Error Codes**
>
> - **Event ID: 1000:** Exception code: 0xc000027b
> - **Event ID: 5961:** Error code: Unknown HResult Error code: 0x80040904. Activation phase:    COM App activation

### **Some of What I've Tried**

I've tried running the below PowerShell and reinstall the applications that have this problem, and it appears to run without error, but the problem still occurs.

```
$wAppPath = (Get-AppxPackage -Name "*Calc*").InstallLocation;
Add-AppxPackage -Path "$wAppPath\Appxmanifest.xml" -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode;
```

- I've also ran `sfc /scannow` and a few different `dism` commands, rebooted, and the problem persists regardless of all these things I've tried.
- I've also looked over and took a stab at some solutions listed in the [Metro apps crash on startup, driver or permissions issue?](https://superuser.com/questions/432859/metro-apps-crash-on-startup-driver-or-permissions-issue) post too.
- And some of the solutions mentioned in the [Windows 10 Edge Opens Momentarily and Then Disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/962642/windows-10-edge-opens-momentarily-and-then-disappears) post, and nothing seems to resolve.

### **Further Detail**

This problem seems to only occur with accounts configured as [auto logons](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) which have their profiles deleted at shutdown and startup both (yes both) using the [DelProf2](https://helgeklein.com/download/) method.

### Event Viewer Details

**Event ID 1000**

> ```
> Faulting application name: Calculator.exe, version: 10.1812.1901.4008, time stamp: 0x5c304989
> Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.18362.356, time stamp: 0x0825b5b0
> Exception code: 0xc000027b
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000712cf0
> Faulting process id: 0x1518
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d568dbe3b0f42c
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1812.10048.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
> Report Id: 23d86f95-8eec-407b-b52c-86043d6d0426
> Faulting package full name: Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1812.10048.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
> Faulting package-relative application ID: App
> ```

- [image]

**Event ID 5961**

> ```
> Activation for Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed. Error code: Unknown HResult Error code: 0x80040904. Activation phase: COM App activation
> ```

- [image]

Comment: Please note this same problem was occurring on Windows 10 version 1803 and upgrading to 1903 did not resolve the problem as a mentioned solution from one of the linked SU posts in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to resolve this problem is to register the applicable UWP [Provisioned Windows apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/apps-in-windows-10#provisioned-windows-apps), and each of those applications' dependencies. Below is some PowerShell logic that is run while logged on as a user account experiencing the problem, with a login script, etc. and fixes the issue.

> **Note:** This may only need to be run once to resolve this problem for others, my situation may be more on the unique side than the norm.

I confirmed that this PowerShell solution fixes this with at least two UWP apps (*e.g. Calc and Photos*). I figured out the PowerShell after looking over some of the logic in the **Program.cs** on [GitHub here](https://github.com/SN29856L/RegAllAppX) after confirming a run of the **RegAllAppX.exe** located there also resolves the problem.

The execution of that executable file on GitHub takes way too long to run, in my case at least as it needs run at every logon of the account with the problem as it gets a new profile each time it logs onto Windows 10 automatically. I think [DelProf2](https://helgeklein.com/download/) is not wiping the profile properly  and causing the problem but a more native solution is on the back burner for now but may come in the future.

Looking over some of the logic in the [Program.cs](https://github.com/SN29856L/RegAllAppX/blob/master/Program.cs) code you can research, test, and translate to equivalent PowerShell logic to perform similar operations in a more targeted and efficient manner for the specific UWP apps that experience the problem.

### PowerShell

```
$Apps = @("WindowsCalculator","Photos");

$base   = @();
$depend = @();
$Apps | %{
    $base   += $base   = (Get-AppxPackage -Name "*$_*").InstallLocation;
    $depend += $depend = (Get-AppxPackage -Name "*$_*").Dependencies.InstallLocation;
    };

$Apps = (($base + $depend) | Sort -Unique);
$Apps | %{Add-AppxPackage -Path "$_\Appxmanifest.xml" -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Get-AppxPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=win10-ps)
- [Add-AppxPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps)

  > - You can use the `Register` parameter to install from a folder of unpackaged files during development of Windows® Store apps
  > - You can use `DisableDevelopmentMode` to register an application that is staged by the **StagePackageAsync** API, has been disabled, or has become corrupted during testing.
- [About Assignment Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-6)

  > **`+=`**:    Increases the value of a variable by the specified value, *or
  >   appends the specified value to the existing value*.
- [Sort-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Set-Alias: `sort`
- [PackageManager Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager)